# String.Format is misaligned horribly for some reason

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextarea, string.format

I'm used to using printf, but my research led me to believe I could use String.Format for setting up tables in a JTextArea and that it was essentially the same thing. This is for a rhythm game app. My code is:

```
private final String HEADER = "%-10s%-15s%-90s%-9s%-6s%-9s%-7s%-6s%-9s";
...
ranks.setText("");
ranks.append(String.format(HEADER + "\n", "Rank", "Difficulty", "Song Name",     "Perfects", "Goods", "Averages", "Misses", "Boos", "MaxCombo"));
ranks.append(analyze.toString());
...
return String.format("%-10d%-15d%-90s%-9d%-6d%-9d%-7d%-6d%-9d\n ", rank, difficulty,   songName, perfects, goods, averages, misses, boos, maxCombo);
```

for each component in an array analyze.toString returns the string shown. My format strings are identical sans everything being strings in the header and most everything being integers in the table so I don't know why my table comes out looking like this:

[image]

Comment: What font are you using? You need to use a fixed with font for such alignments.

Comment: It may not be your whole problem, but from the image, it looks like you are using a proportional font. If you want things to line up, you're going to have to use a fixed-width font.

Comment: Don't wanna sound like captain obvious, but why don't you use a JTable?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! I'll try the fixed width font first and if it doesnt work I'll use a JTable. I've made a lot of GUIs, but I didn't even know JTable existed!

Answer (score 5):

Like stated in the comments you should use a [fixed-width font (or monospaced font)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) for such alignments to work.

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
area.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Or as stated Denis Tulskiy, directly use the JTable component.