# Java displaying Jlabel.setText with a formatted String

Tags: java, swing, jframe, string-formatting, jlabel

So currently I'm trying to display a text on screen with java which has been preformatted but when it's printed out in a textbox is like it's never been formatted.

My current output is:
"I like spacing"

and i wish to get this:
"         I      like    spacing"

This is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public GUI() {
        String test = String.format("%10s %10s %10s", "I","like","spacing");

        label.setText(convertToMultiline(test));
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));

        panel.add(label);

        add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static String convertToMultiline(String orig)
    {
        return "<html>" + orig.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
    }
}
```

Comment: JLabel doesn't support that type of formatting. You need to manually add the spaces.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453067/string-format-is-misaligned-horribly-for-some-reason. It seems a Monospace font would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  StringBuilder for this. Append your string to it and also you can use html tags to help you build what you want.